# Trouble understanding python generators

Tags: python, generator

I am new to generator in python. I have a simple enough code which I am playing with but I can not understand the output I am getting out of it. Here is my code :

```
def do_gen():
    for i in range(3):
        yield i

def incr_gen(y):
    return y + 1

def print_gen(x):
    for i in x:
        print i

x = do_gen()
y = (incr_gen(i) for i in x)
print_gen(x)
print_gen(y)
```

I expected my output to be like this :

```
0  1  2 
1  2  3
```

But I am seeing only :
    0  1  2

I do not understand this output. Can anyone please help me sort out my lack of understanding? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your generator is exhausted when you reach the last line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generators (like all iterables) can only be iterated over *once*. By the time `print_gen(x)` is done, so is `x`. Any further attempts to get new values from `x` will result in `StopIteration` being raised.

This works:

```
x = do_gen()
y = (incr_gen(i) for i in do_gen())
print_gen(x)
print_gen(y)
```

as that creates two separate *independent* generators. In your version, the generator expression you assigned to `y` expects `x` to yield more values.

It is easier to see that the `x` generator is shared with `y` when you use the `next()` function on them in turn:

```
>>> def do_gen():
...     for i in range(3):
...         yield i
... 
>>> def incr_gen(y):
...     return y + 1
... 
>>> x = do_gen()
>>> y = (incr_gen(i) for i in x)
>>> next(x)  # first value for the range
0
>>> next(y)  # second value from the range, plus 1
2
>>> next(x)  # third value from the range
2
>>> next(y)  # no more values available, generator done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Note the `StopIteration` raised by `next(y)` as well here.

Comment: Or rather: generators return an iterator, which is the thing that can only be iterated over once.

Comment: @AlexThornton: generally speaking, generators are a specialized iterator.